# Hadwiger number and minimal degree (II)

Tags: graph-theory, graph-colorings, graph-minors, hadwiger-conjecture

This is a follow-up on an [older question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/239923/hadwiger-number-and-minimal-degree).

Suppose $G$ is a finite simple graph and $\eta(G)$ is the maximum $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $K_n$ is a minor of $G$. Let $\delta(G)$ is the minimal degree of $G$. As Fedor Petrov [showed](https://mathoverflow.net/a/239925/8628), we do not necessarily have $\delta(G) \leq \eta(G)$.

**Question.** Is there necessarily an induced subgraph $G_0$ of $G$ with $\eta(G_0) = \eta(G)$ and $\delta(G_0) \leq \eta(G_0)$?