# Can $\delta(G)$ get arbitrarily large in relation to $\eta(G)$?

Tags: graph-theory, graph-minors, hadwiger-conjecture

For any finite, simple, undirected graph $G$, let $\eta(G)$ be the maximum $n$ such that the complete graph $K_n$ is a [minor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_minor) of $G$, and let $\delta(G)$ be the minimum degree of $G$.

In [certain graphs](https://mathoverflow.net/a/239925/8628) we have $\delta(G) > \eta(G)$.

**Question.** Given a positive integer $n$, is there a graph such that $\delta(G) \geq \eta(G) +n$?

Comment: Doesn't [this comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/239923/hadwiger-number-and-minimal-degree/239925#comment689981_239926) by Tony Huynh imply a positive answer?